# dSYM Path im Azure Pipeline for iOS

Tags: ios, azure-pipelines

I have created an Azure pipeline for iOS and now trying to integrate AppCenter SDK to get crash logs. For this I need to upload the symbols as well. I'm trying to understand what should be the path for dSYM path in Azure ?

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below answer could help you achieve what you want? If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave comment here :-)

Answer (score 2):

Although its late, just for answering the question:

Below path is working for me:
`**/*.dSYM/**`

Comment: this doesn't work for me..

Answer (score 0):

The dSYM path is relative path from the repo to root to dSYM folder.

Crash reports show the stack traces for all running threads of your app at the time a crash occured. The stack traces only contain memory addresses and don't show class names, methods, file names, and line number that are needed to read and understand the crashes.

To get these memory addresses translated you need to upload a dSYM package to App Center, which contains all information required for symbolication.